# How to apply rights to specific IIS Users?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an application in which i have MAP drives. I cannot allow permission to everyone to upload or create files/folders. Only Few IIS Users are allowed to upload files.  I am able to access folder when i allow permission to everyone on folder but as i remove everyone and allow specific user it gives error:"Access to path is denied". Kindly help and explain in detail if possible.

Answer (score 0):

One ASP.NET applicaion works under one user in IIS, i.e. the application pool user. So, you should give right permission to the application pool user, but if you would like to restrict the upload rights, then you should create rules for your ASP.NET application users. So, you should login in your ASP.NET applicaiton and to have rights to upload the files on the server.

Regards